# How to Convert this Coditional formatting formulas into VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, xcode

I am having an issue converting my specific formula parameters into VBA code. Ive tried many ways but there always seems to have an issue.

When opening conditional formatting box, I have:

```
Formula= J5>0. Format: Black font Red fill. Applies to: =$K$5:$K$509.
```

Ive achived the final result, all I need is to somehow write this into VBA

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  This isnt a code writing service, so please post what code you have tried and I also suggest reading [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, what is your final goal?  The benefit of conditional formatting is that that it is automated behavior in the worksheet.  A macro is just the same - automated behaviors.  Why do you need to build a robot to run your other robot?

Comment: @RyanB. Often we need to generate dynamic sheets on the fly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints for your VBA coding:

- To get an object representing a **range** use the `Range` function: `Set myRange = Range("K5:K509")` and to avoid ambiguity you can use the `Range` method defined on the `Worksheet` class: `Set myRange = myWorksheet.Range("K5:K509)"`
- To access conditional formatting use `Range.FormatConditions`, e.g. to add a new conditional formatting: `Set myFC = myRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=...")`
- To change the style of the cell if the condition matches use the resulting object: `myFC.Interior.Color = vbRed`